# Copy Paste UIElement (FrameworkElement)

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, clipboard, copy-paste

I have a **Designer** exactly how is the `VisualStudio` `WinForms` designer.

I drag & drop there controls (`FrameworkElements`) (from a **ToolBox** with controls).
Controls are stored into a `Grid` `Panel`.

Actually I'm going to implement the **Copy/Paste** functionality for `UIElement`(s). 
[image]

I put the Selected control to `Clipboard`

```
private readonly DataObject _dataObject = new DataObject();
```

The **Copy** method it's working OK, it stores the element in Clipboard.

```
private void CopyUIElementToClipboard(FrameworkElement element) {       
    _dataObject.SetData(element);
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(_dataObject);
}
```

But on **Paste** I have problems. I cannot retrieve the element from clipboard.

```
public void PasteUIElement() {
    var control = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.***); //What type should i give it here ?

    //I tried all formats from DataFormats via this. But all returns NULL.
    TryAll();

    //Continue doing other stuff 
}
```

//Trying all formats inside `DataFormats` but all return NULL

```
private void TryAll() {
    var qBitmap = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
    var qCommaSeparatedValue = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);
    var qDib = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Dib);
    var qEnhancedMetafile = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.EnhancedMetafile);
    var qFileDrop = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    var qHtml = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Html);
    var qLocale = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Locale);
    var qMetafilePicture = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.MetafilePicture);
    var qOemText = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.OemText);
    var qPalette = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Palette);
    var qPenData = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.PenData);
    var qRiff = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Riff);
    var qRtf = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Rtf);
    var qSerializable = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable);
    var qStringFormat = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat);
    var qSymbolicLink = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.SymbolicLink);
    var qText = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
    var qTiff = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Tiff);
    var qUnicodeText = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText);
    var qWaveAudio = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.WaveAudio);
    var qXaml = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Xaml);
    var qXamlPackage = _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.XamlPackage);
}
```

How can I retrieve the `FrameworkElement` element from `Clipboard` ?

I tried to store only the name of my element to clipboard and to Paste it in Notepad. It was working fine.

```
private void CopyUIElementToClipboard(FrameworkElement element) {    
    var elementName = element.Name;
    _dataObject.SetData(DataFormats.Text, elementName, true);

    Clipboard.Clear();
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(_dataObject);
}
```

But inside my project, how to get things done with **Paste**, i'm in a little trouble.

Maybe I should store it in `Clipboard` in another format (`Serializable`, or something other)

Any suggestion will be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by using the `XamlWriter`:

```
var xaml = XamlWriter.Save(element);
```

I was able to put in Clipboard via:

```
var xaml = XamlWriter.Save(firstElementOnly);
          _dataObject.SetText(xaml);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(_dataObject);
```

After that I'm retrieving from `Clipboard` in this way:

```
var xamlElement= _dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
```

and with

```
var xamlString = new StringReader(xamlElement);
var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(xamlString);
var uiElement= (UIElement)XamlReader.Load(xmlTextReader);
```

I'm transforming it into `UIElement`.
This way you can store `UIElement`s in `Clipboard`.

Comment: link to XamlWriter class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.aspx